# String array to multiple objects

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, logic

I have a string array

```
String[] weekDays
```

weekDays represents days of week. for eg

```
{1, 2, 4} means Monday, Tuesday, Thusday
{2,5,6,7} means Tuesday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
```

I have seven boolean representing 7 days of week and have to set true or false on the basis of weekDays.

My code

```
private static void setWeekDays(final Object object, final String[] weekDays) {
    for (String day : weekDays) {
        if( day.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            object.setMonday(true);
        } else if( day.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            object.setTuesday(true);
        } else if( day.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            object.setWednesday(true);
        } else if( day.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
            object.setThrusday(true);
        } else if( day.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
            object.setFriday(true);
        } else if( day.equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
            object.setSaturday(true);
        } else if( day.equalsIgnoreCase("7")) {
            object.setSunday(true);
        } 
    }
}
```

But it has so many if else statements and before performing this i explicitly set all booleans to be false.
Is there any other simple way to do the same thing? Any suggestion ??

Comment: +1 for showing effort. I'd like to see what 'setSunday', for example, does though. It looks to me like those 'set..' functions could be unnecessarily specific to each day. If you could pass a 'set...' method the value of the string and it does XYZ you could do all this with one line of code as opposed to an if or switch.

Comment: Basically there are 7 fields in the database with respect to seven days to set all these field there are seven methods.

Comment: Seven methods is excessive then. You should be able to implicitly refer to these DB fields based on the value passed and any more info of your DB schema. Add the code of your set methods to the OP.

Comment: @DeeMac sorry i am npot getting your point. So can you please describe the same you mentioned

Comment: u can think of using switch-case and do: Integer.parseInt(day);

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try to use ENUM for this.

For example

```
public enum WeekDay {
   MONDAY("1");

   private String value;

   private WeekDay(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   public static WeekDay find(String value) {
       for (WeekDay weekDay : values()) {
           if (weekDay.value.equals(value)) {
               return weekDay;
           }
       }
   }
```

So then you can use this ENUM as field of your DTO.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my problem is not to store these things.But I recrive input from a source which is an array and to read that array I have to set seven boolena variables.

Answer (score 2):

Define an Enum to be your days of the week:

```
 enum DayOfWeek { 
     MONDAY, TUESDAY, etc.
 }
```

Create a map to go from string to day:

```
 Map<String, DayOfWeek> dayByString = new HashMap<String, DayOfWeek>();
```

Fill the map with all lookups you want, i.e.

```
 dayByString.put("1", DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
 dayByString.put("2", DayOfWeek.TUESDAY);
```

Now to look up the day just do:

```
 DayOfWeek day = dayByString.get(str);
```

This will return null if there is no match - or the matching day of the week.

Now instead of your 7 booleans use an EnumSet:

```
 Set<DayOfWeek> days = new EnumSet<DayOfWeek>(DayOfWeek.class);
```

Internally that will use a bitfield to represent the days so will be incredibly fast and space efficient.

To set the flag do `days.add(day);`

To unset it do `days.remove(day);`

To check if it is set do `days.contains(day);` or `days.contains(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);`.

```
private static void setWeekDays(EnumSet<DayOfWeek> set, final String[] weekDays) {
    set.clear();
    for (String day : weekDays) {
        set.add(dayByString.get(day));
    }
}
```

You are done, that's all you need.

EnumSet is the correct way to store this. There are other options but 7 booleans is flat out wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my problem is not to store these things.But I recrive input from a source which is an array and to read that array I have to set seven boolena variables.

Comment: And my example does that. I'll add a bit more

Comment: I can't use EnumSet. these 7 boolean is mapped with 7 fields in Db using hibernate.

Comment: Actually you can, using a custom hibernate mapping although I'm not sure off hand how that would be done, that's a separate question anyway though. If you have 7 separate booleans then there is nothing you can do to make the mapping better as you need to reference each boolean by different code.

Comment: Well, you could using reflection but that's even more dirty than what you have.

Comment: Solution provided by Prashant Thakkar seems more logical in my case

Comment: Either way you need to change the DTO. He's using a HashMap where and EnumMap would be better, and an EnumMap to boolean is better replaced by an EnumSet... which brings you back to my solution though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

1. Add following code in your DTO Object

   List weekDaysList;

   ```
   private void setWeekDays(String[] weekDays){            
       weekDaysList = Arrays.asList(weekDays);
   }

   private boolean isWeekdaySet(String weekday){
       if (weekDaysList == null || weekDaysList.size() == 0){
           return false;
       }
       return weekDaysList.contains(weekday);
   }
   ```
2. update each of the getMonday, getTuesday method as follows:

```
public boolean getMonday() {
    return isWeekdaySet("1");
}

public boolean getTuesday(){
    return isWeekdaySet("2");
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: what  is the use of hashMap int his solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the DTO class can NOT be modified, you could try to make a method mapping previously, and use reflection to call the target method, like this:

```
private static Method[] methods;

private static void init() throws Exception {

    Class klass = BusTravelDetailDTO.class;
    String[] methodNames = new String[]{null, "setMonday", "setTuesday", "setSunday"};
    methods = new Method[methodNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        if(methodNames[i] != null) {
            methods[i] = klass.getMethod(methodNames[i], Boolean.class);
        }
    }
}


private static void setWeekDays(final Object object, final String[] weekDays) {

    for (String day : weekDays) {
        methods[Integer.parseInt(day)].invoke(object, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

But, since you have only seven choices, `if-else` might be the most simple and efficient way.

If the DTO class can be modifie, use `enum` instead of seven boolean flags.